# Does C# plugin 5.0 for SonarQube ignore csharpsquid:S3217 rule?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

I updated C# plugin from ver 4.5 to 5. In order to validate the plug-in upgrade, I did an analysis before and after. "After analysis" showed 6 issues less than "before analysis". Note that there was no change to code between before & after analyses (the only difference is before was scanned with C# plugin 4.5 and after was with 5.0). Both analyses were run in **preview mode**.

When I diffed the generated report, I noticed that there were 6 instances of ""Explicit" conversions of "foreach" loops should not be used (csharpsquid:S3217)" which were missing in after analysis.

Is there a reason why 5.0 plug-in would no longer consider this as an issue? Is anyone else seeing this?

PS: We're on SonarQube 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some fine tuning of the rule S3217 lately to reduce noise produced by the rule. Specifically, on legacy code the rule reported a lot of issues, and therefore we modified it as part of https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-769

Note that the rule description has also changed. See the exception part of the [rule documentation site](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/rules/index.html#sonarLintVersion=2.0.0&ruleId=S3217), which says

> The rule ignores iterations on collections of objects. This includes
>   legacy code that uses ArrayList. Furthermore, the rule does not report
>   on cases when user defined conversions are being called.